# How to evaluate the lambdify function for this example?

Tags: python, lambdify

I'm new to Python. I trying Sympy and Numpy.

I have this expression in sympy as follows

```
x, n = symbols('x n')
expression = (2/n)*sin(n*x)
f = lambdify( [x,n], expression, "numpy")
f(a,b)
```

x value ranges are like say `a = numpy.linspace(0,numpy.pi)`

n is a simple array, say `b = numpy.linspace(1,6,6)`

In paper, first I will substitute n values in the expression and then evaluate the expression at each values of x.

the last step of `f(a,b)` won't do my job. And it clearly won't.

I tried it, `x = [numpy.linspace(0,numpy.pi) for x in range(6)]` 
But this is not the way I guess.

How I can do it?

Edit.

```
I tried using this and it works fine.
f = sympy.lambdify([x,n], (2/n)*sy.sin(n*x), "numpy")
a = numpy.linspace(0,numpy.pi)
y = f(a,1)+f(a,2)+f(a,3)+f(a,4)+f(a,5)+f(a,6)+f(a,7)
```

But I want to reach f(a,50).